# Why does this space matter in this regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Why does the space make all the difference?

```
select * from beds where id~'.*Extra large.* (Red).*';
```

and

```
select * from beds where id~'.*Extra large.*(Red).*';
```

The first one returned nothing and the second acted as I wanted. An example of what I want matched is:

```
"Extra large" (Red) {2012 model}
```

I thought the first would work since there is a space after (Red)?

EDIT:Even if I escape the brackets with '\' I still can't have a space there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not escaped your brackets around `"Red"`. Your regex should be:

```
'.*Extra large.* \(Red\).*'
```

This makes the brackets literal brackets, but without escaping them they create a regex group (and not characters to be matched).

Your first regex grouped the characters `Red` and required a space to precede that group `Red`, so it would match `"... Red..."`, but there is a bracket in your input before `Red`, so it doesn't match.

Your second regex accepts any character(s) (via `.*`) before `Red`, so it matches.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're not escaping the `()`.

The brackets around "Red" create a group and are not included in the match. This
is the reason why the regexp without the whitespace works.

The `.*` in the regexp **without** the whitespace matches `" (`, then comes `Red` and after that `) {2012 model}`. The brackets are matched by the `.*` operators.

The `.*` in the regexp **with** the whitespace matches `"` and the `(` is not included in the pattern.

So the right pattern would be this:

```
.*Extra large.*\(Red\).*
```